# Jersey REST API returning 404 not found deployed in tomcat

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I have developed REST API through JAX-RS Jersey in Eclipse.
In Eclipse,i have configured Tomcat 8.0.21 server.
In Eclipse, i do Run As -> Run on Server, 
Tomcat Server runs successfully, and i able to hit the end points and  getting proper response.
So far so good.
Next step,
Using Eclipse, i did export the project as WAR File.
Unzipped the Tomcat server to a directory in windows
Copied the WAR file in webapps directory
Copied the necessary jars to lib folder 
Below are jars i copied to lib folder

- jersey-container-servlet-core-2.23.1.
- jar jersey-server-2.23.1.jar
- java-client-2.3.1.jar
- jersey-media-moxy-2.23.1.jar
- gson-2.7.jar

Clicked on startup.bat in bin.
I can see - my war is deployed successfully and
server is running successfully.
However, when i try hit the same endpoint, i get 404 not found.
Please help, What Am i missing

This is how my pom.xml looks

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ecom.subhash</groupId>
<artifactId>couchdb</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>couchdb</name>

<build>
    <finalName>couchdb</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
    <filters>
      <filter>
        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
          <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
          <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </filter>
    </filters>
  </configuration>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer
            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
          <transformer
            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
              <Main-Class>ecom.subhash.couchdb.resource.App</Main-Class>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: Did you see tomcat's log?

Comment: What do you mean with 'i try hit the same endpoint'? Are you using the default url `localhost:8080/warname/` ? Check also in your workspace the directory `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\` You will find there a deployment of your app made by eclipse. Check differences with your deployment